# iOS - sending email

Tags: ios, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm sending an email with very trivial method

```
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h> 
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMessageComposeViewController.h>

-(void) sendEmailto: (NSArray*)p_recipient withSubject:(NSString*)p_subject body:(NSString*)p_body andAttachment:(NSData*)p_attachment
{
MFMailComposeViewController *emailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    emailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] == YES)
    {
        [emailComposer setSubject:p_subject];
        if(p_recipient != nil)
        {
            [emailComposer setToRecipients:p_recipient];
        }
        if (p_body!= nil && [p_body isEqualToString:@""]==NO)
        {
            [emailComposer setMessageBody:p_body isHTML:NO];

        }
        if(p_attachment != nil)
        {
            [emailComposer addAttachmentData:p_attachment mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"image.jpg"];
        }

        // Present mail view controller on screen
        [emailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        [self presentModalViewController:emailComposer animated:YES];
        self.sentEmailTargetController = p_target;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't Open Email");
    }

}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"e-mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"e-mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"e-mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"e-mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (![[self presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed])
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

I have the declared `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` delegate in the interface

running it on my device the email console opens, I can write a message, clicking on send closes the email window but doesn't actually send the email. The method  `- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error` **logs email sent** but the mail does not reach it's destination. tried several email accounts.

Comment: FYI - don't check `BOOL` values against `YES` or `NO`. Change `if (someBool == YES)` to simply `if (someBool)`. And change `if (someBool == NO)` to `if (!someBool)` (notice the `!`).

Comment: @rmaddy every coder ha it's own style of coding your remark is like telling me not to write { in a line of its own and place it at the end of a code line...

Comment: Actually, my comment is not based on style but on actual functionality. Direct comparisons to `NO` and `YES` can actually result in code that doesn't work as expected. In most cases it will likely work but in some cases it may fail and it will be a very difficult bug to track down.

Comment: @liva Listen to what you are told. Try to remember that you are the one asking a question; this means you do not know. What rmaddy is telling you is _crucial_. It is not a matter of style. Your code is _wrong_ and can easily lead to wrong results. `canSendMail` (or any BOOL) can be true without equalling YES. Never, never, _never_ compare a BOOL against YES or NO; just use the BOOL _directly_ as a condition.

Comment: @matt i did remove the comparison to YES,NO it still doesn't work! and it does log it as sent

Comment: That's fine. I didn't say that would change your results. I said that @rmaddy was right and you should not dismiss what he is saying.

Answer (score 1):

> I can write a message, clicking on send closes the email window but doesn't actually send the email

This is in fact within the spec, as [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/):

> Using this interface does not guarantee immediate delivery of the corresponding email message

Lots of things can go wrong, lack of Internet connection being among the most obvious. And of course even if the email is sent, that is no guarantee that it will reach anyone; other things can go wrong down the line.

Comment: is there a better method to send email?

Comment: No, because no matter what you do, you are ultimately using the same engine as the Mail app (unless, of course, you write your own SMTP client, or adopt an existing one, like this: https://github.com/jetseven/JSMailSender). Your way has always worked on my device. I don't know what is actually going wrong in your case, but I don't think there's you can do that you're not doing.